# C++ reference to local temporary object

Tags: c++

Consider the following template class

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    virtual T const& getContent() = 0;
};
```

I derive this class using 'int*' as type 'T', as follows

```
class A1 : public A<int*> {
private:
    int a;
public:
    int* const& getContent() { return &a; }
};
```

I got the following warning: 'returning reference to local temporary object'.

Questions:

1. Does the compiler implicitly instantiate a local temporary object of type 'int * const' from '&a' before returning its reference?
2. As I do know that A.a really exists, then can I just ignore this warning? Will there be any undesirable side-effects of using this code?
3. What is the proper way of handling this situation? Do I need to work with the member variable 'int *a' instead. This would be cumbersome.

Comment: `T const& getContent() = 0`: Did you meant `virtual T const& getContent() = 0`?

Comment: That `getContent` function should probably be declared `const` as well.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes.
2. You cannot ignore this warning. `A.a` exists, but that's not the issue. What you are returning is not a pointer to `int`, but a reference to a pointer to `int`, i.e. it is a double indirection. To be specific, a temporary `int*` was created inside `getContent` that pointed to `A.a`. A reference to that temporary was returned, and then the temporary was destroyed. Using the result of `getContent` will be undefined behavior.
3. The idiomatic way to handle this situation would typically be to store the member you are passing a const reference to. In other words, have a member `int* a`, and then simply return `a` in your function. Returning a const reference is a common way to expose the fully functionality of a data member without allowing the user of the class to mutate it, messing up your class' invariants.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
T const& getContent() = 0;
```

You can do:

```
T const getContent() = 0;
int* const getContent() { return &a; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

```
int* const&
```

Is the same as...

```
int *const&
```

**Edit**: Originally, I wrongly stated it was equivalent to `const int*&`. Sorry, that was my fault.

And, references to pointers are more "cumbersome" than pointer themselves (at least IMHO), don't you think so? There's a reason pointers and references shall never be mixed (unless it's a consecuence of template instantiation, of course)...

```
int const&*
```

This is impossible, invalid, and last but no least, insane. Although there's no practical way for references to be implemented other than by pointers, they are *not* objects, in the sense that they (themselves) don't have a `sizeof` that does not equals that of their referenced type, and the fact that they don't have address at all, at least as far as the Sacred Writings of N4296 are concerned.

But... pointers *are* objects! The expression `&a` returns a rvalue (that is basically an object without an address) of type `int*`. Now, the statement `return &a;` will take that value and wrap it up in a reference, because...

- That's what the function return type expects.
- The lifetime of an rvalue of type `T` can be extended by means of it being holded in a reference of type `const T&`. However, you can't use this to return references to temporary rvalues.

Now, because all this stuff implies that you're returning a reference to a temporary rvalue in an unallowed way, you where tempted and falled into Undefined Behaviour.

The solution? Simply don't use references to pointers at all in the first place...

```
int const *getContent() { return a; }
```

Or, if you prefer it, use references, but not pointers...

```
int const &getContent() { return *a; }
```

Now, to the questions!

- *Does the compiler implicitly instantiate a local temporary object of type 'int * const' from '&a' before returning its reference?*: Yes and no. It does instantiate such a temporary as explained above (but usually optimized away), but it's type is `int*`, not `int *const`, although the latter gets implicitly casted into the former.
- *As I do know that A.a really exists, then can I just ignore this warning? Will there be any undesirable side-effects of using this code?*: That depends on whether you would ignore a divide-by-zero warning.
- *What is the proper way of handling this situation? Do I need to work with the member variable 'int *a' instead. This would be cumbersome.*: You may either use "cumbersome" pointers or "beatiful" references, see above.

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: I'm 99% sure that `int* const&` is not equivalent to `const int*&`. `const` binds to the type token to its left (unless it's the left most token, then it binds right for convenience). `const int*&` is a reference to a pointer to a `const int`; `int* const&` is a reference to a `const` pointer to non-`const` `int`. `const int*&` _is_ equivalent to `int const *&`, but not `int* const&`.

Comment: Pointers and references do get mixed in real code all the time, especially generic code. Consider a vector<in*>. Quite useful in some situations. What is the return type of operator[] for such a structure? Also, I'm curious if you're the one who down voted the other two answers; if so I'd like to know why.

Comment: Well, that would be a special case :). I meant mixing them explicitly. Better off edit that part, then. BTW, why do you ask if I downvoted those questions? I wasn't the one who downvoted them, neither I have any reason to do so.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Sorry, my fault. You're right, so I'll edit my answer. I would usually have noticed the difference between `const int*` and `int *const`, but references + pointers do mess up my mental type parsing.

Comment: My bad, it's just that both were down voted at nearly the same time you answered.

Comment: @NirFriedman: Well, I accept that too suspicious, but I promise you I haven't.

Comment: @NirFriedman: BTW, I upvoted your answer (but not the other; actually, I consider the downvote was reasonable for the other answer) and made a few changes to highlight the fact that it's brevity is by no means a reason to downvote it ;) (at least I thought that would be the "reason" the downvoter made what he/she did).